# How to find start and end of a string

Tags: python, string, if-statement

Intention is to write a function that would reverse the words in a string. So that if the input is: "I am a student" the output should be "student am a I"

I have the following code in Python which first reverses all the characters in a string and then loops the reversed sentence to reverse the words and prints them to a "final sentence" variable.

Because the condition I am checking for is just a space, the first word doesn't get printed i.e. if the input is " I am a student" my code works (notice the space before "I") ... however if the input is "I am a student" then the output is just "student a am"

I need to know how can I modify my IF statement so it doesn't miss the first word

```
def reverse(sentence):
    count = 0
    new_sentence = ''
    final_sentence = ''
    counter = 0
    word = ''

    for char in sentence[::-1]:
        new_sentence = new_sentence + char


    for char in new_sentence:
        if char != " ":
            count = count + 1
            continue
        else:
            for i in new_sentence[count-1::-1]:

                if i != " ":    
                    word = word + i
                else:
                    break

        count = count + 1
        final_sentence = final_sentence + " " + word
        word = ''
    print final_sentence

reverse("I am a student")
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are doing such complicated loops? You can just split the sentence, reverse and then join it again:

```
>>> ' '.join('I am a student'.split(' ')[::-1])
'student a am I'
```

To translate that into a function:

```
def reverse_sentence(sentence):
    return ' '.join(sentence.split(' ')[::-1])
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. However, "where is the error in this method" seems like a valid question, and you haven't addressed that. For whatever reason (education?), OP is unrolling they're own solution, so it seems like you should address why his method doesn't work correctly for a complete answer

Comment: You don't have to have the single quotes as a split argument. The default argument for split() is one blank space. Also, Python already comes with a built-in reversed() function. So the solution could be as easy as:

`return " ".join(reversed("I am a student".split()))`

Comment: As en_Knight pointed out this is indeed for a class and am trying to do this without having to use spilt, join, reversed or any other built-in Python functions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're doing several strange things in your code. For example:

```
new_sentence = ''
for char in sentence[::-1]:
    new_sentence = new_sentence + char
```

The string you're building through concatenation is already present in `sentence[::-1]`. You could've just done `new_sentence = sentence[::-1]`.

You can check for the first word by using `enumerate()` and checking whether there is a space prior to that point in the sentence:

```
for idx,char in enumerate(new_sentence):
    if char != " " or ' ' not in new_sentence[:idx]:
```

However, the easiest way to accomplish your actual goal is with `split()`, splitting the sentence by whitespace automatically. Use `join()` to put it back together once you've reversed it.

```
def reverse(sentence):
    return ' '.join(sentence.split()[::-1])
```